# PHP GD library losing quality. Other ideas?

Tags: php, image, gd, resize

So I'm in the middle of working on a website that deals with photographs.  A user uploads their original photograph and GD library creates a smaller sized image of the same photo.  However, when comparing a manually sized down image with the GD one, the GD image seems to lose quite a bit of color quality like it had been slightly desaturated. Any alternate suggestions or ways to improve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advice using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for handling anything serious about photos.

besides quality, you'll find using [imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) functions like more convenient

```
Imagick::cropThumbnailImage()
Imagick::thumbnailImage()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`imagecopyresampled`](http://in.php.net/imagecopyresampled) instead of [`imagecopyresized`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php). It gives much better quality. Also, try NOT to use `GIF` images as output.

Comment: The desaturation your seeing is probably because gd is removing the color profile.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, the answer is imagemagick.  Easier to use and maintains the full photograph quality!